# Ignore firebase related exceptions in Roboelectric unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

My Roboelectric unit tests are giving this exception when I try to initialise Firebase in the Application class.

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process null. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.`

Is there any way where I can ignore this exceptions and get my tests pass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not need firebase in your test, you can annotate the test class with

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(application = Application.class)
```

to use a different application from your app custom application.

Answer (score 1):

As an option you can use mockStatic from mockito:

```
mockStatic(FirebaseFirestore::class.java)
    .use { firebaseFirestore ->
        firebaseFirestore.`when`<Any> { FirebaseFirestore.getInstance() }.thenReturn(mock(FirebaseFirestore::class.java))
}
```

Comment: can you check my mockito question as well I cant find solution for last one day

Answer (score 0):

Organize your code so that it isn't reliant on a Firebase connection and pass in a mock?  Its generally not a good idea to have unit tests rely on a remote service, that's more the realm of integration tests or acceptance tests.

Or alternatively-  do the initialization in an @Before if that's too hard?

Comment: Completely agreed on this point. But the problem that I am facing is that Firebase docs says that we should initialise FirebaseApp in the onCreate of our Application. So even if I use a mock or something, still Roboelectric calls the onCreate of Application and throw out the exception.